# Dúvida quanto a Segurança, Autenticação e Autorização

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá, estou com dificuldades em montar uma arquitetura na parte relacionada a segurança da aplicação. Preciso que apenas usuários logados e devidamente autorizados tenham acesso a determinadas funções da aplicação. Sei que normalmente poderia utilizar a autorização baseada em Roles, mas o problema é que nas regras de negocio dessa aplicação são os usuários(Master) que criarão os perfis de acesso, sendo assim não tem como eu pré definir nos filtros quais serão as Roles que terão acesso a cada controller/action da aplicação.

Alguém teria alguma solução para o cenário que descrevi?
A arquitetura será construída em Asp.Net MVC5 C#, com Entity Framework e AutoFac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se entendi corretamente seu problema, é que seus *Roles* não podem ser pré-definidos. Imagino também que você vai poder ter um meio de adicionar novas *Roles* à vontade (como você disse, um usuário *Master* criando os perfis).

Nesse caso, usaria o banco de dados para gravar as *Roles* já criadas, incluindo a informação de qual rota/*controller*/ação é permitida para aquela *Role*. Defina também um relacionamento associativo entre os usuários e *roles* (basicamente falando "estes usários tem essas *roles*").

Em seus *Controllers*, em vez de usar o `[Authorize]`, implementaria uma `AuthorizeAttribute` personalizado, e em vez de confirmar se o usário tem uma *Role* baseando em uma das `string`s (sendo isso a função do `[Authorize]`, confirmaria se o usuário tem uma *Role* que deixa acessar esse *Controller*/rota/ação.

<sub>(Desculpe o português, e se não for claro, por favor me avise!)</sub>

Comment: É exatamente o que estava prestes a sugerir como solução! (:

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar sua própria solução ou usar uma pronta.

Uma boa solução pronta é o [Fluent Security](http://www.fluentsecurity.net/). Ele tem pacote NuGet e é bem simples de instalar. [Aqui tem um pequeno tutorial](http://www.fluentsecurity.net/getting-started).

Outra opção é implementar seu próprio atributo de autorização (resposta do @brazilianldsjaguar). [Aqui tem várias perguntas e respostas que podem ajudá-lo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=AuthorizeAttribute). Basta criar sua lógica e colocá-la dentro do método `AuthorizeCore` do [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

Este método devolve `True` se o usuário está apto a visitar uma determinada parte do código e `False` em caso contrário.